# Шифрование на Питоне

Tags: python, шифрование, поиск-библиотек

Посоветуйте библиотеку для шифровки и расшифровки на Питоне.

Comment: RSA вот [пример](http://stuvel.eu/files/python-rsa-doc/usage.html#encryption-and-decryption)

Comment: Каким образом расшифровку вы предлагаете? Если мы говорим о серьезных шифрах, то их можно расшифровать только за время больше вселенского. А от прочих шифров просто нет толку.

Answer (score 4):

- [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) -  MD5, SHA-1,SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512
- [pycrypto](http://www.pycrypto.org) - Python Cryptography Toolkit

А также поиск по категориям: http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=401&c=400

Answer (score 3):

Вдобавок к PyCrypto - [KeyCzar](http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/), это чтобы было проще работать.

Answer (score -1):

Материал нашёл на сайте:
https://bookflow.ru/shifrovanie-i-kriptografiya-v-python/

Заходим в терминал и вводим строку:

```
pip install hashlib
```

А потом пишем код python:

```
import hashlib
sha = hashlib.sha1(b'Hello Python').hexdigest()
print(sha) # ВЫВОД - 422fbfbc67fe17c86642c5eaaa48f8b670cbed1b
```

Comment: Выше уже рекомендовали hashlib, вы невнимательны